# AngularJS parsing JSON

Tags: json, angularjs

I have the following JSON:

at `http://localhost:3000/folder/1234567`

```
[

   {

      "_id": "543e95d78a1cec2a38ed53ec"

   },

   {

      "_id": "543e95d78a1cec2a38ed53f1"

   }

]
```

And I want to get all the _id.

So, I am doing something like:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/folder/' + folderId)
                        .success(function (response) {
                    console.log("response"+ response);
                    console.log("response id"+ response.id);
```

But I have:

```
response [object Object],[object Object]
response id undefined
```

How can I fix to get the _id ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The response is an Array so you have to loop over it. Which `_id` do you need?

Comment: How can I proceed with an Array? All the _ids. Thanks!

Comment: it depends what you want to do with your data. if you want to display them, just put the data to your scope and use ng-repeat in your view. or if you want to do something else, you can use angulars foreach or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the Ids in reverse order:

```
var allIds = [];

$http.get('http://localhost:3000/folder/' + folderId).success(function(res) {
    for (var i = res.length-1; i>-1; i--) {
        allIds.push(res[i]._id);
    }
    // this prints an array with all the Ids 
    console.log(allIds);
});
```